# Hive 'is null' check problem for struct fields

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql, parquet

Seems like there is strange behaviour for NULL checks for struct fields.
Condition `where some_struct_field is not null` returns rows where `some_struct_field` actually is null.
Does anyone come acrossed this problem or have any advises how to deal with that?

Storage format: parquet
Hive version: 2.2.0

Schema looks like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event(
  key STRING,
  ts BIGINT,
  info STRUCT<
      id: BIGINT,
      message: BIGINT>
)
PARTITIONED BY(event_date STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/logs/events';
```

Query with incorrect result:

```
SELECT * FROM event where event_date = '20200401' and info is not null;
```

Query with correct result:

```
SELECT * FROM event where event_date = '20200401' and info.id is not null;
```

Comment: Please provide some data example (struct)

Comment: @leftjoin I found example in jira.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-24066

Comment: I found solution. null check for sub field works! (select * from event info.id is not null)

Comment: @sngjuk yes, such query works, it's mentioned in the question